# Binomial identity reference request

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, reference-works

Math Overflow answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/297916/113033 references the binomial identity

\begin{equation}
    \sum_{t} \binom{r}{t} \frac{(-1)^t}{r+t+1} \binom{r+t+1}{j}
    =\begin{cases}
         \frac{1}{(2r+1) \binom{2r}r}, & \text{if } j=0;\\
         \frac{(-1)^r}{j} \binom{r}{2r-j+1}, & \text{if } j>0.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

However, I did not succeed in search of literature reference of it.

Is there any literature mention of it or proof?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since OP is also asking for a proof ....

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We start with the easy part:

> - **$j=0$:**
>
>   We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{\sum_{t}}\color{blue}{\binom{r}{t}\frac{(-1)^t}{r+t+1}}
>   &=\int_{0}^1\sum_{t}\binom{r}{t}(-1)^tz^{r+t}\,dz\tag{2.1}\\
>   &=\int_{0}^1z^r(1-z)^r\,dz\tag{2.2}\\
>   &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2r+1}\binom{2r}{r}^{-1}}\tag{2.3}
>   \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

**Comment:**

- In (2.1) we use $\frac{1}{n+1}=\int_{0}^1z^n\,dz$.
- In (2.2) we factor out $z^r$ and apply the binomial theorem.
- In (2.3) we we write the reciprocal of a binomial coefficient using the *[beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)*
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{n}{k}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_0^1z^k(1-z)^{n-k}\,dz
  \end{align*}

> - **$j>0$:**
>
>   We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{\sum_{t}}&\color{blue}{\binom{r}{t}\frac{(-1)^t}{r+t+1}\binom{r+t+1}{j}}\\
>   &=\frac{1}{j}\sum_{t}\binom{r}{t}\binom{r+t}{j-1}(-1)^t\tag{3.1}\\
>   &=\frac{1}{j}\sum_{t}\binom{r}{t}[z^{j-1}](1+z)^{r+t}(-1)^t\tag{3.2}\\
>   &=\frac{1}{j}[z^{j-1}](1+z)^r\sum_{t}\binom{r}{t}(-1)^t(1+z)^t\tag{3.3}\\
>   &=\frac{1}{j}[z^{j-1}](1+z)^r\left(1-(1+z)\right)^r\tag{3.4}\\
>   &=\frac{1}{j}[z^{j-1}](1+z)^r(-z)^r\\
>   &=\frac{(-1)^r}{j}[z^{j-1-r}](1+z)^r\tag{3.5}\\
>   &=\frac{(-1)^r}{j}\binom{r}{j-1-r}\tag{3.6}\\
>   &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{(-1)^r}{j}\binom{r}{2r-j+1}}\tag{3.7}
>   \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

**Comment:**

- In (3.1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (3.2) we apply (1).
- In (3.3) we factor out terms independent of $t$.
- In (3.4) we use the binomial theorem.
- In (3.5) we apply $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (3.6) we select the coefficient of $z^{j-1-r}$.
- In (3.7) we use $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.

Comment: Typo on the last line? Good work! (+1).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Typo corrected. Many thanks! :-)

Comment: Is there typo in (3.2) in binomial coefficient $\binom{r}{j}$, should be $\binom{r}{t}$?

Comment: @PKK: Yes, many thanks. Typos corrected.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and clear answer

Comment: @PKK: You're welcome. :-)

Comment: FYI: This answer is used as reference in the work: https://kolosovpetro.github.io/pdf/HistoryAndOverviewOfPolynomialP.pdf

Comment: @PetroKolosov: Interesting paper. Many thanks for this information and your citation of my MSE post.